# Does .First() operate at linq level or on the returned enumerable collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I came across a colleagues code and thought it was possibly inefficient

```
bool any = (from c in listDeviceMaxDate
             where c.DeviceKey == m_deviceList[i].deviceKey
             select c).Any();

if (!any)
{
    latestDate = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
}
else
{
    // from the list we have get the lastest max date from the flow table
    DeviceDateTimeItem temp = (from c in listDeviceMaxDate
                                where c.DeviceKey == m_deviceList[i].deviceKey
                                select c).First();

    latestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(temp.dateTimeMax);
}
```

My first instinct is to store the linq query and then just reference it as needed but then I realised that the `First()` operator may prevent linq from actually getting ALL the rows which an unconstrained query would do.

How I initially thought about restructuring the code:

```
var deviceList = from c in listDeviceMaxDate
                            where c.DeviceKey == m_deviceList[i].deviceKey
                            select c;

if (!deviceList.Any())
{
    latestDate = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
}
else
{
    // from the list we have get the lastest max date from the flow table
    DeviceDateTimeItem temp = deviceList.First();

    latestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(temp.dateTimeMax);
}
```

My question is does the `First()` call on the second linq query prevent it from returning all results, and as such, is it actually quicker to do it the original way?

Comment: Is this Linq to SQL? `First()` operating on an `IEnumerable<T>` is Linq. `First()` on an `IQueryable<T>` from `System.Data.Linq` is Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on what LINQ implementation it is. If it is LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`), then it is *basically* just enumerating the data *whatever it is*, and returning the first item if one. So `First()` is the moral equivalent of:

```
foreach(var val in sequence) return val;
throw OopsNoData();
```

and `Any()` should compare well to:

```
foreach(var val in sequence) return true;
return false;
```

(it probably uses a raw iterator in the actual implementation, rather than `foreach`)

However! If it is LINQ-to-anything-else, all bets are off. LINQ queries (especially `IQueryable<T>`) are designed to be composable - and I would expect LINQ-to-SQL, for example, to make `First()` into a `select TOP 1 ...` TSQL query, and similarly for most other database-backends. So yes, telling it that you only want one row should be helpful. However! I would also expect `.Any()` to do something very similar, so that shouldn't (in theory) be a big difference. In a perfect world, it might even use `exists(...)` in the TSQL, but the world is far from perfect.

The way to find out: attach a sql tracer, and see what the final TSQL was.

---

The ultimate way to do this is simpler:

```
var obj = someQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if(obj == null) {
   // no match
} else {
   // do something with "obj"
}
```